Screenshot of the Week #117
This contest is over.
previous contest | next contest
Hello and welcome to the 117th edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! nobody's screenshot from shadow-the-hedgehog won with 11 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-06-10, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-06-17, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

No theme
There is no theme this week.
As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Catching golden hour out on the water somewhere in England in assassins-creed-valhalla


That's some nice lighting



serious-sam-siberian-sayhem

Wait, that's a Serious Sam game? Damn, so much changed since the first encounter.

Pancakes!

oneshot

For anyone curious, OneShot is a PC game available on Steam. To be played on Windows for the best experience out of it.

Great, now I want pancakes..

@Joachim To be fair, I hesitated to post this for the "Video Game Food" edition of SOTW. I figured I'll just post it as a "random unknown game".

@Clockwork if you don't win this comp, you can always re-submit it the next time there's a food theme :)

The last sunlight catches a-plague-tale's Château d'Ombrage, temporarily transcending its ominous designation:


A city dead for a thousand years. Zanarkand in final-fantasy-10


Listen to my story. This... may be our last chance.

At this point the game had caught me in. until the bitter end.

A block of ice made using the Cryonis Rune in zelda-breath-of-the-wild breaks when a Sentinel rams into it, yet this block's taken 6 shots from its cannon and is still standing


I'm beginning to think I should consider purchasing a Switch to play this game.

@Clockwork Definitely worth the investment

You should, both BotW and TotK are a masterpiece

Truth be told, the only things holding me back are budget and the fact I'm more of a PC guy.

@Clockwork Switch emulator: https://git.suyu.dev/suyu/suyu (No idea how to get the ISO legally, but you could buy the game without actually using that copy, that is how I did it with Mario Odyssey.)

Showing off my new polearm in lords-of-the-fallen 

What are those blue lines behind you?

That's my Umbral Lamp
